# How to find volume from Washer method?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, volume

So, I want to use Washer method to find 
$$\pi \int_{y=0}^2 (\sqrt{4y})^2-(\sqrt{4y}-0.1)^2 dy.$$

I've literally spent a day trying to do so, and when I treat each part separately and then subtract the answer keeps resulting in 
a) a negative
or 
b) two drastically far apart numbers

Hence, I think something is wrong in the initial set up.  Any thoughts on what is wrong?

Comment: I just tried it again. Seems fairly straightford to me at first, but then my result was 0.06205cm-- which seems impossible given that the distance between the lines is 0.1cm for the majority of its length

Comment: The washer method is a mnemonic for _setting up_ a correct integral when finding the volume of a solid of revolution. Once you have an integral (which you seem to have here), the washer method has done its job, and all that's left is pure calculation.

Comment: Okay. must be some problem in the calculation.

Comment: It should be $\pi(0.4*2^{3/2}*2/3-0.02)$. Pay attention to the position of the factor $0.4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your graph it seems that you are considering the solid obtained by rotating the curve about the **$y$-axis**. Is it correct?

Why don't you simplify before integrating?
$$(\sqrt{4y})^2-(\sqrt{4y}-0.1)^2=0.4 \sqrt{y}-0.01.$$
It remains to evaluate
$$\pi\left(0.4 \int_0^2 \sqrt{y}\,dy -0.01 \int_0^2 \,dy\right)=
\pi\left(0.4 \left[\frac{2y^{3/2}}{3}\right]_0^2 -0.01 \cdot 2\right).$$
What is the final result?

Comment: Sorry where did the last ∫1dy come from?

Comment: I think the result is 2.3595..., does that seem correct to you? Thank you!

Comment: I got $2.3067$. You may write simply $∫dy$. BTW may I see the original statement of your problem?

Comment: Would you mind expanding on how you simplified it for me? I'm afraid I'm quite weak on integral rules, etc. since I've been mostly trying to learn how to do this through google, and missed a few bits. Thanks!

Comment: Just note that $(\sqrt{4y}-0.1)^2=(\sqrt{4y})^2-2\cdot 0.1\cdot \sqrt{4y}+(0.1)^2$.

Comment: Why is the last line $2y^3/2$ rather than just $y^3/2$? and why is $0.1$ multiplied by 2? Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to do with the final $\int dy$? Why is that there?

Comment: We have that $\int y^{1/2} dy= \frac{y^{\frac{1}{2}+1}}{\frac{1}{2}+1}+c$ and $\int_a^b dy=b-a$.

Answer (score 3):

If you're rotating about the $x$-axis, you need functions in terms of $x$ for the first quadrant:

$$
x=\sqrt{4y}\implies y=\frac{x^2}{4},\\
x=\sqrt{4y}-0.1\implies y=\frac{(x+0.1)^2}{4}.
$$

Your integral should look like this where $2$ is supposedly the upper bound of integration:

$$
V=\pi\int_{0}^{2}\left[\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)^2-\left(\frac{[x+0.1]^2}{4}\right)^2\right]\,dx.
$$

If you're rotating about the $y$-axis, then your integral looks fine. There must have been a mistake in your calculations:

$$
V=\pi\int_{0}^{2}\left[\left(\sqrt{4}y\right)^2-\left(\sqrt{4y}-0.1\right)^2\right]\,dy=\\
\pi\int_{0}^{2}\left[4y-\left(4y-0.2\sqrt{4y}+0.01\right)\right]\,dy=\\
\pi\int_{0}^{2}\left(4y-4y+0.2\cdot 2\sqrt{y}-0.01\right)\,dy=\\
\pi\int_{0}^{2}\left(0.4\sqrt{y}-0.01\right)\,dy=\\
0.4\pi\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{y}\,dy-0.01\pi\int_{0}^{2}\,dy=\\
0.4\pi\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2^3}}{3}-\frac{2\sqrt{0^3}}{3}\right)-0.01\pi(2-0)=\\
0.8\pi\frac{\sqrt{2^2\cdot 2}}{3}-0.02\pi=\\
0.8\pi\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}-\pi\frac{0.02\cdot 3}{3}=\\
\pi\left(\frac{0.8\cdot 2\sqrt{2}}{3}-\frac{0.06}{3}\right)=\\
\pi\frac{1.6\sqrt{2}-0.06}{3}\approx 2.31\ \text{cubic units}.
$$

This is easy to integrate. Just remember that $\int\sqrt{x}\,dx=\frac{2\sqrt{x^3}}{3}+C$ and $\int\,dx=x+C$.

Comment: Apologies, i think i mistyped x rather than y.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused about what's going on in the 3rd to 4th lines-- if you change $ \sqrt (4y)$ to $2(\sqrt y)$, where does the $\sqrt 4y$ come from in line 4?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to remove the $4$ when I was copying things. I fixed it now.

Comment: Also why is $\pi$ both a constant and after 0.01 in the 5th line? and where does the 0.06 come from?

Comment: I edited the answer. Take a look at it again.

Comment: in the third to last line, why is $0.02 * 3$ rather than $0.02^3$ ?

Comment: Because I need to get two terms with a common denominator. Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to add the two fractions. For example, $$\frac{2}{3}+2=\frac{2}{3}+2\cdot\frac{3}{3}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2\cdot 3}{3}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{6}{3}=\frac{2+6}{3}=\frac{8}{3}.$$ That's how you add fractions. I do not raise anything to a power.